# How to let app run until the Countdown timer end task

Tags: java, android

I have problem with Countdown Timer. When I press button the Timer starts and after clossing app and waiting for a while the Timer stops. So the main idea what I want to do is to let app be awake in background process until the Timer Finish. I dont know the code or in which direction I should go. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//paste the following code inside your button method
// mind you the example giving here is countdown for 60 seconds

int yoursecondsLeft = 0;

new CountDownTimer(60000, 100) {
     public void onTick(long milliseconds) {

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////This is the code that convert to real system time so that yo will have your exact seconds//////////////////////////////

```
     if (Math.round((float)milliseconds / 1000.0f) != yoursecondsLeft)
     {  
         syoursecondsLeft = Math.round((float)milliseconds / 1000.0f);

     }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     Log.i("test","ms="+milliseconds+" till finished="+yoursecondsLeft );
```

// You can print the count down value to your texview here: e.g tv.setText(yoursecondsLeft);
     }

```
 public void onFinish() {
```

/*Close your application here: you can now call this method here: finish(); to end your application */

Log.i("finish","Countdown completed");

```
 }
```

}.start();